# Security of mysql with iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, encryption

I have an encrypted connection from my ios app to my mysql database. My question is whether or not they would be able to intercept the connection form the ios app and find the domain with or without an encryption

Comment: You're not actually saving the connection info inside your app, right? that's rather insecure anyway. Unless this app is a generic mysql client, saving the credentials within the app is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Create a PHP interface between your app and the Mysql. Doing this they will be able to hack only app-accounts not the entire database! Your Mysql credential will be stored in the remote domain where the PHP code runs.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. They would not be able to get into the mysql if I have some php in-between?

Comment: @user1776234 Well, it depends on. There can still be SQL injection attacks (where effectively malicious data can be performed for reading or writing the database) and also merely by using PHP instead of a direct connection (I'm wondering how do you want to realize such a "direct" connection) won't prevent an attacker from network sniffing or patching your application. You know, nothing is impossible and there is no system that's absolutely secure.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I do have an sql injection method setup and a few others in my php. However, based on the comments above, it appears that an ip address is detectable. With your answer though, they would have to use normal hack attacks against php which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sql injection CAN be prevented to some extent. You didn't understand my answer. I mean a remote PHP code hosted remotely from the iOS app. Something like iOSapp <-> remote_host_with_php <-> mysql_database. The mysql database could be hosted on the same host where the PHP code resides. It become as hard as to violate a normal web application.

Comment: @G_G That's perfectly right, nobody said that it is a rule that OP will be hacked, and SQL injections can definitely be prevented (just a little attention to be paid to the proper escaping and such). Yet, "If you do XYZ then your data will be secure" is unfortunately (or fortunately, depends on one's point of view) simply not true.

Answer (score 8):

> whether or not they would be able to intercept the connection form the ios app

Yes, they would be able to do so. At least surely using a jailbroken device - for jailbroken devices, there are a couple of factors that make hacking easier.

On the one hand, on a jailbroken system, it is possible to prevent Apple's encryption of the app executable (by dumping the unencrypted program code from memory to the disk) and run a utility called "class-dump" to obtain the Objective-C class information (it is also possible to use the GDB debugger on the device or IDA Pro in order to reverse engineer the application logic).

On the other hand, the same MobileSubstrate library that is used for making iOS tweaks can be used to alter the behavior of any given application (I have successfully used this technique for circumventing some code obfuscation at runtime), so in theory an attacker would alter the communication logic of your application and dump the unencrypted data of yours and your users.

[On the gripping hand](http://catb.org/jargon/html/O/on-the-gripping-hand.html), most standard and less-used Unix utilities usable for such kind of hacking are ported/compiled for jailbroken iOS - including the popular network sniffing tool `nmap`, the "John the Ripper" password cracker, the infamous `aircrack-ng` WEP/WPA key cracker, the GNU debugger (GDB), etc. These are also useful for executing an attack you described.

If the connection itself is encrypted, then, in theory, your data should be safe *while in the wire.* This still doesn't prevent the MobileSubstrate-based approach to exploitation. It is also true that the IP address of the server you're connecting to can be found relatively easily (end even the domain it is matching, since there are also known techniques for obtaining reverse-DNS information using a known IP address).

I'm not sure if this is possible without a jailbreak, but a similar man-in-the-middle attack was performed against Apple's in-app purchases by a Russian hacker (effectively rendering ineffective the underlying payment system and allowing purchases to be freely downloaded), merely by requiring users to install SSL certificates, profiles and using the hacker's own proxy server, so I'd suspect it is possible even without a jailbreak. Note that in this case the connection was also encrypted, and it was not the encryption that mattered.

Comment: Excellent, thorough answer.  +1

Comment: Good answer, however it seems to come down on jailbreaking quite a bit. This is easily possible without a jailbroken device. To get the domain I could crack the binary and then open it with IDA, or strings. The SSL certificate trick will also work to decrypt encrypted communications between the server. Jailbreaking makes it more convenient (all on device), but it's always possible.

Comment: @Freerunnering Isn't that just what I wrote, essentially?

Comment: @H2CO3 essentially. I was mostly commenting on this bit "I'm not sure if this is possible without a jailbreak"

Answer (score 1):

You should not imo create a direct connection to the mysql-database but instead pursue a connection with a server program/api with a connection to the database in question. To answer the question more directly users should not be able to intercept the connection from the ios-app if it is encrypted correctly but still, is it worth that risk?

Comment: "*users should not be able to intercept the connection*": a cracker could always reverse-engineer the executable and extract encryption keys, so this method is *never* secure (and that's assuming that keys are embedded rather than exchanged with authentication through some other means, e.g. a certification authority that could be more easily circumvented by simply setting the device to trust one's own CA and then perform a classic MITM attack).

Comment: Well yes. But I assumed that his question was about sniffing the trafic and trying to intercept data that way. Hell, even that may very well be possible but is highly unlikely. After all I did recommend an extra layer as an api.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is encrypted, the data are secure. But not the domain. The iPhone is connecting to an IP Address, and that IP Address is obviously not encrypted.

Comment: "Security" is never absolute, so "*the data are secure*" can never be correct.  Resistent to a certain level of attack, yes; but not impenetrable.

Comment: "If the connection is encrypted, the data are secure" - nope, see my answer. (**Do not want me to proof it.** I'm sure you love to be the only one who knows your passwords. :D)

Comment: @eggyal touchè :-) I agree with the fact that security is relative and saying "the data are secure" is relative to the security level you have given to your data, of course ;-) My answer was focused on the "connection / domain" question.

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree with you. I've answered quickly focusing on the second part of the question (the connection part). There are a lot of system to "unsecure" data... ;-)

Comment: Based on the answers, as long as I have a secure php method inbetween with security measures, I am fine regardless of whether they can get my domain